# Testing React15 with Enzyme and Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm new to React and am having some problems with testing.
I'm adding tests List.test.js in Ryan Walsh's most excellent learner project on Github: https://github.com/r-walsh/react-unit-test-practice.

This submitToDo() test passes:

Function:

```
  submitToDo = text =>
      this.setState(() => ({
      toDos: [{ complete: false, text }, 
      ...this.state.toDos],
      }));
```

Test:

```
  it('adds new ToDo to state', () => {
      const list = shallow(<List />);
      list.setState({
          toDos: [
              { complete: false, text: 'One'},
              { complete: true, text: 'Two'},
          ],
      });
      list.instance().submitToDo('Three');
      expect(list.state().toDos.length).toBe(3);
      expect(list.state().toDos[0].text).toBe('Three');
```

});

The toggleCompletion test does not pass. The debugger tells me that "text" has no value when toggleCompletion is called. If I remove ({ }) from the text argument, the test passes but the toggle no longer works in the browser.

Function:

```
  toggleCompletion = ({text}) =>
      this.setState(({ toDos }) => ({
      toDos: toDos.map(
          toDo =>
              toDo.text === text ? { complete: 
              !toDo.complete, text } : toDo,),
   }));
```

Test:

```
  it('toggles completion', () => {
      const list = mount(<List />);
      list.setState({
          toDos: [
              { complete: false, text: 'One'},
          ],
  });

  expect(list.state().toDos[0].complete).toBe(false);
  list.instance().toggleCompletion('One');
  // todo test fails, but this works in the browser
  expect(list.state().toDos[0].complete).toBe(true);
```

});